# Finding an element in partially sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I had a following interview question.

There is an array of nxn elements. The array is partially sorted i.e the biggest element in row `i` is smaller than the smallest element in row `i+1`.
How can you find a given element with complexity O(n)

Here is my take on this:

You should go to the row n/2.And start compare for example you search for 100 and the first number you see is 110 so you know it's either in this row or in rows above now you go n/4 and so on.

From the comments

> Isn't it O(n * log n) in total? He has
>   to parse through every row that he
>   reaches per binary search, therefore
>   the number of linear searches is
>   multiplied with the number of rows he
>   will have to scan in average. – Martin
>   Matysiak 5 mins ago.

I am not sure that is a right solution. Does anyone have something better

Comment: Sounds correct to me. O(log n) to reduce to two candidate rows, O(n) to find the element in one of those rows. That's O(n) total.

Comment: You can't do better than binary search in a sorted array and you can't do better than a linear search in an unsorted one, so this seems optimal to me.

Comment: Is correct. Binary search, then linear search. You're not going to get better than O(n), because of the unsorted rows.

Comment: Isn't it O(n * log n) in total? He has to parse through every row that he reaches per binary search, therefore the number of linear searches is multiplied with the number of rows he will have to scan in average.

Comment: I think Martin is right does anyone have an idea to do it O(n)?

Comment: Does the `n` in O(n) refer to the n in nxn?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your solution indeed takes `O(n log n)` assuming you're searching each row you parse. If you don't search each row, then you can't accurately perform the binary step.

`O(n)` solution:

Pick the `n/2` row, instead of searching the entire row, we simply take the first element of the previous row, and the first element of the next row. `O(1)`.
We know that all elements of the `n/2` row must be between these selected values (this is the key observation). If our target value lies in the interval, then search all three rows (`3*O(n) = O(n)`).

If our value is outside this range, then continue in the binary search manner by selecting `n/4` if our value was less than the range, and `3n/4` row if the value was greater, and again comparing against one element of adjacent rows.

Finding the right block of 3 rows will cost `O(1) * O(log n)`, and finding the element will cost `O(n)`.

In total `O(log n) + O(n) = O(n)`.

Comment: Actually by searching over the rows and comparing with the first (or any) value of a row) you limit the possible rows to 2 not 3.

Comment: @dcn, not true. `{ 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 8 7 9 }` searching for any of `{2,5,7}` will yield that the target is indeed in the range `[1,8]` and yet to find the value I need to search all 3 rows, if I don't I'm not going to find one of the values.

Comment: No. Search for '2'. Compare to '5', which is bigger -> can only be in row 1&2. Same argument goes for searching 5 and 7.

Comment: My bad. I thought you were comparing with elements from consecutive rows, but reading it once more, prev and next are not supposed to be neighbors.

Comment: You could of course reduce it to 2 possible rows like this: via binsearch you find the smallest index of a row, **maxrow** , such that the first element of **maxrow** is bigger then the element you are looking for. Then only **maxrow** and **maxrow-1** are candidates

Comment: @davin: The array is unsorted, so how can you guarantee that the "rows-in-consideration for finding the number", will be between the first element of the previous row and first element of the next row ?

Comment: @brainy, read the question, the array is **not** unsorted, it is partially sorted (if it were unsorted, there would only be the trivial way to search, being to traverse the entire array). That's why I called that point the "key observation". Think about it, and in 5 minutes if you still don't see it, let me know.

Comment: @davin: "ah!" :) so, you are utilizing the fact that rows are ordered and narrow down the rows from thereon.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple implementation - since we need *O(n)* for finding an element within a row anyhow, I left out the bin-search...

```
void search(int n[][], int el) {
    int minrow = 0, maxrow;
    while (minrow < n.length && el >= n[minrow][0])
        ++minrow;
    minrow = Math.max(0, minrow - 1);
    maxrow = Math.min(n.length - 1, minrow + 1);
    for (int row = minrow; row <= maxrow; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < n[row].length; ++col) {
            if (n[row][col] == el) {
                System.out.printf("found at %d,%d\n", row, col);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At first I was puzzled as to why you used a linear search through the rows, but then the penny dropped...  O(n) + O(n) = O(log n) + O(n) = O(n), so why be fancy if you don't need to!  :) (Of course if it was an m*n matrix then for optimality you'd need the binary search after all...)

Comment: @dcn - Can you please explain the logic behind  the calculation of minrow and maxrow?